# Using Forms Authentication with WebAPI when the client is in a different domain?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Related question:

[Authentication in .NET Web API using MVC FormsAuthentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15902409/authentication-in-net-web-api-using-mvc-formsauthentication)

I have a client application that lives outside of my WebAPI solution's domain (right now two different solutions on localhost - one on port X, the other on port Y).  I'm attempting to use forms authentication with code like this:

```
if (WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: true))
            {
                var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "logged in successfully");
                return response;
            }
```

In something like POSTMan this works, but using the client / JS application, the cookie does not get saved, so the user is never truly authenticated.  I see the _RequestVerificationToken, but never the .ASPXAUTH token.

A requirement of this application is to use forms auth by setting cookies using WebSecurity.  Is this possible when client and server are on different domains?

If there's anything else I can provide to make this issue clearer, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using CORS. By default, cookies are not enabled with CORS. In jQuery, you need to set

```
xhrFields: {
       withCredentials: true
}
```

Also, the server must send the response header `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true`.

Comment: Disregard my previous comment - everything is working.  Thank you SO much - you saved me countless hours.